# Should I perform annual maintenance on our heating boiler?

Tags: hvac, boiler, water-circulating-heating

We are new to having a boiler in our house. Should we be doing an annual inspection and cleaning of our boiler? One was done last summer. How often should the system be purged too? Thanks for clearing this up for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The oil boilers I'm familiar with should be inspected and tuned annually.

Many newer gas boilers need  preventative maintenance only once every two years.

I suspect pellet boilers want attention every year, but that is a guess.

Comment: ...and the inspection and tuning is not really a DIY job, IMHO.